# AndroidRuntimeException when clicking URL in Activity

Tags: java, android, runtimeexception

I have an Activity with an Adapter that `extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserProfileAdapter.ViewHolder>`. The problem is that when a User clicks on an "autolink" in one of the list items, I get the following exception:

In my UserProfileActivity, I instantiate my adapter like his:

```
UserProfileAdapter adapter = new UserProfileAdapter(getApplicationContext(), posts);
```

In the adapter, I retrieve the context like this:

```
    private Context mContext;
    private List<ParseObject> mYeets;
    private UserProfileAdapter adapter;

    public UserProfileAdapter(Context context, List<ParseObject> yeets) {
        super();

        this.mYeets = yeets;
        this.mContext = context;
        this.adapter = this;
    }
```

[image]

How can I make sure that autolinked text does not produce this error? Since there is no code associated with the link/intent, what do I even do?

Comment: what is unclear in the message you screenshoted?

Comment: The fact that there is no actual Intent that launches the link. It's "autolinked" text in one of the Recycler list items. So I just can't just go and add a flag to the intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`android.util.AndroidRuntimeException` is thrown because in your application is using Application Context to start an activity without the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. Android Runtime does not allow this kind of action because there is no Stack to add this new Activity and the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag is important to create a new Stack in your application.

To resolve it, you can pass the Activity context to the Adapter instead of Application Context (i.e.: use `this`).

e.g.: `UserProfileAdapter adapter = new UserProfileAdapter(this, posts);`

**Good Practice**: Always use Activity Context to work with UI elements.